# How to find duplication using select all and group by all

Tags: sql, duplicates, hana

I want to find duplication from a table, let's say users has columns name1, name2, ..., namen.

So to find duplicates in the table:

```
select name1, name2, ...., namen
from users
group by name1, name2, ..., namen
having count(*) > 1
```

But because n is too big, I don't want to write it all in select and group by.
Is there a way to shorten this like:

```
select *
from users
group by *
having count(*) > 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: this is for sap hana, which is similar to standard sql , I think

Comment: you want to say that ,you don't want to use select statement for selecting values ?

Comment: That depends, how do you define duplicate row? if two rows has the same name1,name2 is it enough to say its duplicated?

Comment: no two rows have to have same value from name1 to namen

Comment: You have to list all columns, from name1 to namen. No short-cuts here.

Answer (score 0):

SAP Note SAP Note 1969700 contains a generator script that creates the SQL statement for you.

However, the * shortcut to reference all columns of a table or view is only valid in the select list of the SELECT statement.
That's standard SQL.